# Howto configure gulp-sass compiler to use dart-sass in gulpfile.babel.js?

Tags: sass, gulp, rubygems, babeljs, gulp-sass

**How to set the `sass.compiler` property to use Dart Sass instead of Node Sass, when you are using `gulpfile.babel.js` configuration file, instead of standard `gulpfile.js`?**

The latest gulp-sass documentation states:
"You can choose whether to use Dart Sass or Node Sass by setting the sass. compiler property."

To use node-sass we need to declare this for a `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');
```

Therefore to use dart-sass we need to declare this for a `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('dart-sass');
```

When I compared the difference between the produced compressed CSS files via both "Ruby Sass 3.7.3" and "gulp-sass 4.0.2" it turned out quite a difference between the file sizes.

*This is due to some differences during compilation such as:*

the Ruby one converts `.1em` to: `0.1em`
while
the gulp one is keeping the `0.1em`

and

the Ruby one converts codes such as `\f008` to ``
while
the gulp one is keeping those codes as they are

plus some other bits and bobs.. overall I would like to use the ruby conversions via gulp. I hope that using gulp-sass with dart-sass compiler might be a better solution for my current particular needs.

> **Ruby Sass 3.7.3** can be found here: https://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions/3.7.3
>
> **latest gulp-sass** can be found here: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass
>
> **latest dart-sass** can be found here: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass

Currently, I am using this in my `gulpfile.babel.js`:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import print from 'gulp-print';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import notify from 'gulp-notify';
import size from 'gulp-size';
import fileSize from 'gulp-filesize';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No worries, I have the answer!**

This in my new `gulpfile.babel.js`:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import print from 'gulp-print';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import notify from 'gulp-notify';
import size from 'gulp-size';
import fileSize from 'gulp-filesize';
import dartCompiler from 'dart-sass';
sass.compiler = dartCompiler;
```

Quite pleased with the results, it was a justified switch! Had to go through some recommended SASS related improvements thanks to dart-sass, but in the end, it was worth the extra effort:

`Ruby Sass 3.7.3` produced a CSS file size: 169.2 kB (169,215 bytes)
`gulp-sass 4.0.2` with `node-sass 4.11.0` compiler: 170.4 kB (170,382 bytes)
`gulp-sass 4.0.2` with `dart-sass 1.17.2` compiler: **168.9 kB (168,898 bytes)**

> Please note: your needs may be different and you should consider accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that Babel has two parallel config file formats, which can be used together, or independently. Configuration can be **Project-wide** or **File-relative**

For file-relative configuration, use:

- `.babelrc` (and `.babelrc.js`) files
- `package.json` files with a `"babel"` key

It is important to remember about the `.babelrc` file once taking an older project.

A great preset utility is:

> [@babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) is a smart preset that allows you to use the latest JavaScript without needing to micromanage which syntax transforms (and optionally, browser polyfills) are needed by your target environment(s). This both makes your life easier and JavaScript bundles smaller!

To take advantage of it, add the following to your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
}
```

Comment: I am glad you mentioned the .babelrc config file, it is a good addition to the main answer. Welcome aboard @abacus